# Differential of a smooth function on a manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-derivative, smooth-manifolds

Let $S^2$ be the sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$, let's consider the (inverse) chart $\varphi$
$$x=\sin v\cos u, y=\sin v \sin u, z=\cos v$$
now let $f$ be the restriction of the linear aplication of $\mathbb{R}^3$ given by
$$\left( \begin{matrix}\sqrt{2}/2&0&\sqrt{2}/2\\0&1&0\\-\sqrt{2}/2&0&\sqrt{2}/2\end{matrix} \right)$$
to $S^3$.

I am trying to compute, for any $p\in S^2$, $$f_*(\frac{\partial}{\partial u}|_m)\text{ and }f_*(\frac{\partial}{\partial v}|_m)$$

My first impulse is to calculate $\varphi\circ f\circ\varphi^{-1}$, compute its differential and then each colum would be one of those. But, since this example of a manifold is embeded in $\mathbb{R}^3$, is there any easier way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

This is not an exact answer, but it may be better to compute the differential in a coordinate system which is better suited to your function $f$. Since $f$ is linear, you probably want to choose a (near) linear coordinate system, for instance,

$$
x^{-1}: (u, v) \mapsto (u, \pm \sqrt{1 - u^2 - v^2}, v)
$$

Then

$$
(x \circ f \circ x^{-1})(u,v) = x\left(\frac{u + v}{\sqrt{2}}, \sqrt{1 - u^2 - v^2}, \frac{u - v}{\sqrt{2}} \right) = \left( \frac{u + v}{\sqrt{2}}, \frac{u - v}{\sqrt{2}} \right)
$$

And at least here you can find the intrinsic properties you are more likely interested in, except on the set $\{ (x,y,z) \in S^2 : y = 0 \}$. For instance, that the operator has full rank, etc.